# How to set non focusable labelField inside a GridField

Tags: blackberry

I have developed a application with considering touch screen device for BlackBerry.
But when I am trying to use it in Non touch screen device all the lable also shows the focus.
Basically what I want that LabelField should not show any focus.
 I have set NonFocusable Property for it but still it is not working.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You dont want the LabelField to have focus when you select it on touchscreen ?

Extend LabelField and override onFocus like so -

```
 protected void onFocus(int direction) {


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try overriding the LabelField's `isFocusable()` to always return `false`. It's possible that the GFM is just calling `setFocus()` on the next field without checking whether or not it can actually accept focus. If this is the case you may have to override the GFM's `nextFocus()` method and correct the logic.